# How could I append a certain object from several lists into a new file?

Tags: python, append, data-analysis

I have hundreds of lists of numbers that contain different pressures, and I need to append each 5th object in each list into a new file. What the program is doing is going though hundreds of text files with thousands of lines of data in each. The program goes through each file in the path and separates the data into two lists: Mass_to_charge and Pressure. My code is:

```
import os

os.chdir('file_path')
path = os.listdir('file_path')
for file in path:
    MtoC = []
    Pressure = []
    readfile = open(file,'r')
    line = readfile.readline()
    line = readfile.readline()
    line = readfile.readline()
    line = readfile.readline()
    line = readfile.readline()
    line = readfile.readline()
    line = readfile.readline()
    line = readfile.readline()
    line = readfile.readline()
    line = readfile.readline()
    line = readfile.readline()
    line = readfile.readline()
    line = readfile.readline()
    line = readfile.readline()
    line = readfile.readline()
    line = readfile.readline()
    line = readfile.readline()
    line = readfile.readline()
    line = readfile.readline()
    line = readfile.readline()
    line = readfile.readline()
    line = readfile.readline()

    datalines = readfile.read().split("\n")
    useful_data = []

    for line in datalines:
        line = ''.join([x for x in line if x not in [",", "\r"]])
        data = [float(item) for item in line.split()]
        useful_data.append(data)
    combined_data = [MtoC.extend(sub_list) for sub_list in useful_data]
    Mass_to_charge = MtoC[::2]
    Pressure = MtoC[1::2]
```

If my next line under Pressure is `print Pressure` then it will print me out hundreds of lists of pressures, each with about 1000 objects. I need to append Pressure[4] of each list into a new file. I was thinking that something like:

```
for p in Pressure:
    file.append(p[4])
```

But this didn't work. I also was simply trying to print the 5th object of each Pressure list, but I couldn't figure that out either.

Comment: How about using a loop instead of a gazzilion `readline()`s? :) also, you seem to have *many* files? Is that correct? Can you be more accurate about the input and output and the detailing of your problem?

Comment: The readlines() s were to skip a few files at the beginning of each file. I was on a time restraint for that and meant to clean that up.. I should probably do that some time soon haha. And yeah I'll be more accurate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all use lowercase for variable names. Now, to take the 5th element of each list, from a list of lists, you can use `map` which applies a function to each item and returns the list of results:

```
list_of_fifths = map(lambda x: x[4], Pressure)
```

And example of running this:

```
# create many lists...
>>> list_of_lists = [range(i) for i in range(5, 15, 2)]
>>> list_of_lists
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]]
# take fifth element of each
>>> list_of_fifths = map(lambda x: x[4], list_of_lists)
>>> list_of_fifths
[4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
```

Comment: oh okay, the lowercase thing is just a standard? I've self taught most of my programming. I'll fix this right now. And I'll try this, thank you!

Comment: Did it work? And yeah, uppercase is used for classes, mostly... Just a tip: A great way to learn is to read code other people wrote

Comment: No, it still isn't working. Should the code be indented with the for file in path? I would think so, I have: 

   'pressure = m_to_c[1::2]
    list_of_fifths = map(lambda x: x[4], pressure)
    print list_of_fifths' 

at the end. I want to print it first to check if it is right and my error is 'float' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Where could I look to read other peoples' codes?

Comment: my code should come right after this line: `Pressure = MtoC[1::2]`. If you're getting the error you mention it means you're trying to access an index in a float variable, which is not defined in Python. Something like `a = 1.1; a[4]`

Comment: You have to figure out where are you trying to access an index of a variable you *think* is a list, but is actually a float... :)

Comment: I got it working! I ended up making an empty list called lop=[] and in the loop doing lop.append(pressure). I later had to do list_of_pressures=lop[1:] because there was an empty set as the first item in lop. Then I used the map lambda with list_of_pressures.